# Why does an absolutely positioned image still take up space?

Tags: css

I am trying to make an image a background image in an indirect way: by making an absolutely positioned image. This image is very large. However, I noticed that the image still expands the bounds of my web page. Why is that? It's absolutely positioned, so it shouldn't do that, right?

Here's an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/xeV6t/

The huge seal of Florida is absolutely positioned and centered on the screen with

```
img {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -500px;
    margin-left: -500px;
}
```

but it still takes up space and expands the web page, as shown by how it forces users to scroll. I don't want that expansion to happen. How do I make it go away?

I tried using `overflow:hidden`, but that doesn't achieve what I want - I still want the user to scroll up and down in case the page is long for other reasons.

Comment: If the page grows vertically, you could hide the horizontal overflow by `body {  overflow-x: hidden; }`.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! I'd still like to avoid excess vertical expansion due to the image though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is still a DOM object, which takes up space, absolutely positioned or not

---

**background-size: cover**

You should look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/):

http://jsfiddle.net/QhNRH/

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you put the image as the background-image of your absolutely positioned div, it should do what you need:

```
img {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -500px;
    margin-left: -500px;
    background: url(images/your_image.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Why `background-size: cover`? That's just not what the OP wants.

Comment: Additionally, it being a DOM object isn't the reason why it takes up space. You could `display: none` it and it would not take up space but still be part of the DOM.

Comment: `background-size: cover` loads the image within the confines of the `div`, which is my interpretation of what the OP wants

Comment: Note "I am trying to make an image a background image"

Comment: I appreciate the feedback RE DOM. I was trying to say the image took up the space because it's a single object -- if it was text, it would likely wrap inside the div

Answer (score 1):

```
body
{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

It will hide the horizontal scrollbar.